# SMOTE caused my total nrows in train to fall to a very small proportion

Tags: data-science-model, class-imbalance, smote

I have a highly skewed dataset with minority class in target being just about 4%. I decided to apply SMOTE using library DMwR in R. Here is my target:

```
>table(data$target)
 0      1 
9908 222661 

>prop.table(table(data$target)) 
     0          1 
0.04260241 0.95739759
```

Next I Split my data into train and test with a 70:30 split and then run SMOTE() on the train set.

```
> smoted <- DMwR::SMOTE(target~ ., train, perc.over = 100)
>
> nrow(smoted)
[1] 27640
> nrow(train)
[1] 162799
```

I am unable to understand why the total sample size of smoted data reduced from train. Is there a way to achieve balanced dataset without having to reduce the size of the train set? 
Also, I was worried if it will affect my model if I end up training it over such small train set? (I am running a Random Forest and GBM to help classify the target).